# Post Media to User/Page Wall in Facebook with C# SDK

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm using Facebook .Net SDK(http://facebooksdk.net/) in my application. I need post an image to the wall of the user or his page.

I have this piece of code to try do this:

```
var postUrl = "<fbid>/feed";
var fbParameters = new Dictionary<string,object>();
fbParameters["message"] = postRequest.FacebookPostContent;
if (postRequest.MediaData != null && postRequest.MediaData.Length > 0)
{
     var stream = new MemoryStream(postRequest.MediaData);
     if (postRequest.ContentType.Equals("image/jpeg"))
     {
       postUrl = postUrl.Replace("/feed", "/photos");
       fbParameters["picture"] = new FacebookMediaStream { ContentType = postRequest.ContentType, FileName = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("ddmmyyyyhhmmss") + "-photo.jpeg" }.SetValue(stream);
      }
}
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(postRequest.FacebookPageId))
{
      fbUserID = postRequest.FacebookPageId;
}
postUrl = postUrl.Replace("<fbid>", fbUserID);
var result = await facebookClient.PostTaskAsync(postUrl, fbParameters);
```

Look at my postUrl variable. I update the  with the user ID in Facebook or the PageID if it is a page so the post should be properly posted in the right object. If there is some image to upload, so add it to the dictionary.

So, with it in mind, I have the following questions:

1. When the fbUserID is a user ID, the post happens perfectly, with the image and description but, when the ID is a PageID, only the description text is posted and image is just ignored(the user has the manage_page permissions so I dont think it is a permission issue). What I'm doing wrong that the image is not being posted to the page's wall?
2. If I want to post a video instead of a image, what should I change in this code?

Already saw many problems with other technologies here in SO but never a conclusive solution.

Thank you very much for the help, I really appreciate.

Regards,
Gutemberg

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

Facebook creates a different section inside the page called **Recent Posts by Others on Test Page** where people allowed to post images will be there, like an attachment icon. In order to post directly to the page's feed/wall, all I need to do is instead of use the user access_token(even if user granted manage_pages permission) just use the access_token that comes in /me/accounts object for the respective page.

About the video post, I just set the ContentType to "**video/mpeg**" and at server instead of set **picture** parameter on dictionary, I've set the **video** field with the video byte[].

Thanks!

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you could try the Share Content button shown in one of the answers here:

[Upload video on Facebook using Graph REST API on Windows Phone 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24183960/upload-video-on-facebook-using-graph-rest-api-on-windows-phone-8-1/30108398#30108398)

I found that to be easier than tackling authorization and manually posting.