# Upload video on Facebook using Graph REST API on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, rest, facebook-graph-api, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I want to upload video on Facebook using Graph REST API on Windows Phone 8.1, below given is my code, which doesn't throw exception but not working, just stuck the execution.

```
var backgroundUploader = new BackgroundUploader();
//var fs2 = await videoFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);

backgroundUploader.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + "8af25ae9-b1b4-4ff7-908d-27c3fbe7d78a");
backgroundUploader.Method = "POST";

UploadOperation uploadOperation = backgroundUploader.CreateUpload(
    (new Uri("https://graph-video.facebook.com/me/videos?title=Title&description=Description&access_token=" + accessToken)),
    videoFile);

//It stucks here, no progress for both CreateUploadXXX method

// UploadOperation uploadOperation = await backgroundUploader.CreateUploadFromStreamAsync
//     (new Uri("https://graph-video.facebook.com/me/videos?title=Title&description=Description&access_token=" + accessToken), 
//     fs2.GetInputStreamAt(0));


await uploadOperation.StartAsync();
ResponseInformation response = uploadOperation.GetResponseInformation();
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this doesn't answer the question of how to upload via the graph but as an alternative you could use the Share content to upload a video:

```
 DataTransferManager dataTransferManager;
    private void RegisterForShare()
    {

        if (dataTransferManager == null)
        {
            dataTransferManager = DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView();
            dataTransferManager.DataRequested += new TypedEventHandler<DataTransferManager,
                DataRequestedEventArgs>(this.ShareStorageItemsHandler);
        }
    }

    private async void ShareStorageItemsHandler(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataRequest request = e.Request;

        request.Data.Properties.Title = "Title Here";
        request.Data.Properties.Description = "Description Here";


        // Because we are making async calls in the DataRequested event handler,
        // we need to get the deferral first.
        DataRequestDeferral deferral = request.GetDeferral();


        StorageFile videoStorageFile; // set this somewhere


        // Make sure we always call Complete on the deferral.
        try
        {

            List<IStorageItem> storageItems = new List<IStorageItem>();
            storageItems.Add(videoStorageFile);
            request.Data.SetStorageItems(storageItems);
        }
        finally
        {
            deferral.Complete();
        }
    }
```

And then to bring up the share menu you will need to call:

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI();
```